# Finding dates with identical values in two pandas-timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I have two timeseries with datetime columns as indexes:

```
2012-08-10 1.1       2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2       2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-12 1.8       2012-08-13 1.1
2012-08-14 1.4       2012-08-15 1.3
2012-08-15 1.7       2012-08-16 1.1
2012-08-17 1.6       2012-08-17 1.2
2012-08-18 1.1       2012-08-18 1.1
```

How to compare them and get two timeseries with dates, which are present in both of them:

```
2012-08-10 1.1       2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2       2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-15 1.7       2012-08-15 1.3
2012-08-17 1.6       2012-08-17 1.2
2012-08-18 1.1       2012-08-18 1.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [52]: s1.align(s2, join='inner')
Out[52]:
(2012-08-10    1.1
2012-08-11    1.2
2012-08-15    1.7
2012-08-17    1.6
2012-08-18    1.1,
 2012-08-10    1.1
2012-08-11    1.2
2012-08-15    1.3
2012-08-17    1.2
2012-08-18    1.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation):

```
$ cat in1
2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-12 1.8
2012-08-14 1.4
2012-08-15 1.7
2012-08-17 1.6
2012-08-18 1.1
$ cat in2
2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-13 1.1
2012-08-15 1.3
2012-08-16 1.1
2012-08-17 1.2
2012-08-18 1.1
$ join in1 in2
2012-08-10 1.1 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2 1.2
2012-08-15 1.7 1.3
2012-08-17 1.6 1.2
2012-08-18 1.1 1.1
```

**Edit:** If you want to split both files again, do this:

```
$ join in1 in2 | awk '{print $1, $2}' > out1
$ join in1 in2 | awk '{print $1, $3}' > out2
$ cat out1
2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-15 1.7
2012-08-17 1.6
2012-08-18 1.1
$ cat out2
2012-08-10 1.1
2012-08-11 1.2
2012-08-15 1.3
2012-08-17 1.2
2012-08-18 1.1
```

I *love* small tools :)

Comment: Sorry, I mean using pandas-timeseries. Not using bash-tools.